# Torch.jit.save() What is the difference between saving to file vs. to buffer?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I'm new to Pytorch. The documentation on torch.jit.save mentions 2 ways of saving a TorchScript module to disk.

From Torch.jit docs, see the test code given below (2 arrows):

```
def save(m, f, _extra_files=None):
    r"""
    Save an offline version of this module for use in a separate process. The
    saved module serializes all of the methods, submodules, parameters, and
    attributes of this module. It can be loaded into the C++ API using
    ``torch::jit::load(filename)`` or into the Python API with
    :func:`torch.jit.load <torch.jit.load>`.

    Args:
        m: A :class:`ScriptModule` to save.
        f: A file-like object (has to implement write and flush) or a string
           containing a file name.
        _extra_files: Map from filename to contents which will be stored as part of `f`.

    Example:

    .. testcode::

        import torch
        import io

        class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):
            def forward(self, x):
                return x + 10

        m = torch.jit.script(MyModule())

        # Save to file                        <-------------
        torch.jit.save(m, 'scriptmodule.pt')
        # This line is equivalent to the previous
        m.save("scriptmodule.pt")

        # Save to io.BytesIO buffer           <-------------
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        torch.jit.save(m, buffer)

        # Save with extra files
        extra_files = {'foo.txt': b'bar'}
        torch.jit.save(m, 'scriptmodule.pt', _extra_files=extra_files)
    """
```

What is the difference or advantage of saving to buffer rather than to file?. In what cases should I use one or the other?

Source: https://pytorch.org/docs/1.13/_modules/torch/jit/_serialization.html#load

Answer (score 2):

Saving to a file creates a file on disk with the given name and writes the TorchScript module to it, while saving to a buffer writes the module to a memory buffer (in this case an io.BytesIO object) instead of a file on disk. The advantage of saving to a buffer is that it can be more convenient when you want to store the module in memory and don't want to write it to disk.

In cases where you want to persist the module to disk, you should save it to a file, but if you want to send the module over a network or keep it in memory, you should save it to a buffer. Writing it to a buffer potentially saves time and is used in real time systems.